# Why have my jQuery UI buttons reverted to outsized and generic?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I've used the jQuery UI before to fancify buttons. But now with this code:

```
else if (ui.newTab.index() == 3) {
    $('#MediaContent').load('Content/TwainMedia.html');
    $('#MediaContent').css('background-color', '#000000');
    $('button').button();
    $("button:not(:ui-button)").button();
}
```

...the buttons are outsized and ugly:

[image]

The HTML is like so:

```
<div class="yearBanner">FICTION</div>
<section class="wrapper"><a class="floatLeft" 
href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1456405721" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" 
width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51AxVB0JilL._SL110_.jpg" alt="The Adventures of 
Huckleberry Finn book cover"></img></a>
    <br/><cite class="nobelTitle">The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn</cite>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0448060000" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Hardcover</a>
    </button>
    <button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1456405721" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Paperback</a>
    </button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00L4Q7OA8" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Kindle</a>
    </button>
</section>
<section class="wrapper"><a class="floatLeft" 
href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486400778" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank"><img height="160" 
width="107" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51qa7A+vIsL._SL110_.jpg" alt="The Adventures of 
Tom Sawyer book cover"></img></a>
    <br/><cite class="nobelTitle">The Adventures of Tom Sawyer</cite>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button>
        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486400778" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Paperback</a>
    </button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button>
        <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008TVDBPI" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Kindle</a>
    </button>
    <button><a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BM7ES7G" rel="nofollow noreferrer" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">Audible</a>
    </button>
</section>
```

In _SiteLayout.cshtml, I reference the jQueryUI .js and .css like so:

```
<link href="~/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

What do I need to do to get back my cool blue smaller jQuery-UI buttons?

Note: The jQuery-UI fancification is working on the tabs, as can be seen in the scream shot (the blue "excite-bike" theme is being applied to the tabs as desired).

### UPDATE

My site is [now live](http://twaincentral.azurewebsites.net/); however, the buttons on the media tab are still 9X uglier than a bag of butts.

You can see here how they looked in a previous site whose code I cannibalized for this site (in fact, I simply copied the entire site to a new folder and changed what had to be changed):

[image]

Again, this is the jQuery that worked in the previous site to beautify the buttons with the excite-bike theme:

$('button').button();

...and am referencing jQueryUI like so:

```
<link href="~/css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

...(changed "custom.min.css" to "custom.css") but it still no longer works. Why would that be?

Comment: Is the css file loading in the browser? Are the css files where you actually think they are? ~/ is the application root, which may be different than the web url root. Are the styles applying? Have you inspected what the browse thinks the styles are?

Comment: The theme is being applied to the tabs, so the CSS *is* being loaded, it's just not being applied to the buttons for some reason. I dragged the css file from the solution explorer into the _SiteLayout, so there's no possibility of a typo, etc. Besides, it is working in that one area. Maybe the problem is that jQuery is having a hard time working on a dynamically loaded html file.

Comment: Yes, that could certainly be a problem. If your content is being loaded asynchronously and your button creation is happening on document.ready(), there's a good chance that your button markup doesn't exists when the jQuery UI script triggers. Look into the [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) handler, or make a separate function that initializes your buttons and then call it after your dynamic html loader is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jake Cigar noted on the [jQuery forum thread](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-do-my-jquery-ui-buttons-no-longer-display-the-excite-bike-theme#14737000006117056), the call to jQuery-UI buttonize the buttons needed to come after the HTML was loaded, so this does the trick:

```
$('#MediaContent').load('Content/TwainMedia.html',function(){
      $('button').button();
});
```